# Strongly-typed method interface using yield return

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I really enjoy to be able to do this in C# :

```
IEnumerable GetThePizzas()
{
    yield return new NewYorkStylePizza();
    yield return new SicilianPizza();
    yield return new GreekPizza();
    yield return new ChicagoStylePizza();
    yield return new HawaiianPizza();
}
```

Whereas in Java I would have done it like that :

```
Collection<Pizza> getThePizzas()
{
    ArrayList<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList<Pizza>();

    pizzas.add(new NewYorkStylePizza());
    pizzas.add(new SicilianPizza());
    pizzas.add(new GreekPizza());
    pizzas.add(new ChicagoStylePizza());
    pizzas.add(new HawaiianPizza());

    return pizzas;
}
```

Notice that the Java code tells the type of what is returned (Pizza instances). The C# code doesn't. It bugs me, especially in situations where others programmers don't have access to the source code. Is there a way to fix this?

**Update:** My problem was that I used "System.Collections" instead of "System.Collections.Generic" and therefore I was using the non-generic version of IEnumerable.

Comment: The collections in the System.Collections namespace are somewhat deprecated. Use the generic collections from the System.Collections.Generic namespace unless you have a good reason to use the old, non-generic collections. All fancy stuff in C#/.NET such as LINQ is built around the generic IEnumerable<T> interface.

Comment: I see... I was simply missing the using instruction for System.Collections.Generic. That's why it wasn't working.

Comment: -1 for not including a MexicanHeatwavePizza, but +2 for a nice question ;)

Comment: Note that both codes do completely different things. The `yield`ed pizzas are created on *demand*, just as the resulting collection is looped through.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the generic version of IEnumerable, [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), you can just as easily do this:

```
IEnumerable<Pizza> GetThePizzas()
{
    yield return new NewYorkStylePizza();
    yield return new SicilianPizza();
    yield return new GreekPizza();
    yield return new ChicagoStylePizza();
    yield return new HawaiianPizza();
}
```